# Can't Call setState on an unmounted component even after componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm running into a strange issue with React Router.

I keep getting the warning "`Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component...`" even though I can prove that the component in question is hitting its `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

I'm perfectly fine with ignoring warnings. The thing is, the app isn't working properly because of this.

Current state of my flailing about:

https://github.com/tomizechsterson/chargen-ui

After starting the app, if you click on the '`AD&D 2nd Edition`' link, you can select entries in the table just fine. It's after you navigate away (to either 'Home' or 'D&D 3.5') and back that you can no longer select entries and the warning pops up in the console.

I've tried going through the React Router docs, but wasn't able to figure out what I needed to know to solve this.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that converting a lower-level component to a functional component in my hierarchy avoids this issue. Not sure why, but it's removed my roadblock, so there it is